How does this 230/400 V induction hob draw current?
The instructions that came with a new Electrolux EIS62441 induction hob didn't specify any recommended breaker sizes or supply cable cross section requirements. The hob comes with more than 1 m of preinstalled four-conductor sheathed cable (4*2.5 mm², 2 phases, neutral, PE). The connection diagram as seen on the bottom of the unit:

My assumption is that the unit doesn't work on 400 V at all, instead it draws current from either one or two phases, closing the circuit through the neutral. "2N" seems (to me) to indicate that your neutral wire should be doubled up to be able to cope with the increased I²R.
The source of my confusion is the manufacturer's preinstalled cable. If my assumption is correct, the neutral wire in the supplied cable is going to see ~32 A at peak load, which is nowhere near the rated ampacity of the 2.5 mm² (13-ish AWG) double insulated cord. It's pre-wired for a 2-phase connection.
Can anyone shed some light as to whether these appliances can use the 400 V between the phases or its input power is simply split between the left and right side coils using 2 phases? Does the unit then perform phase angle detection to be able to determine which way it is connected?

The manual should answer how much current it will draw in single phase mode.

"Can anyone shed some light as to whether these appliances can use the 400 V between the phases or its input power is simply split between the left and right side coils using 2 phases?" - it's very difficult to answer this without the manual providing the answer, or reverse engineering effort... modern equipment can be quite flexible in this regard.

Where I live (Brazil), you can use different wire gauges for a given current depending on whether they are buried or exposed (exposed wires dissipate more heat therefore can carry more current). There is no reasonable way an appliance manufacturer will take responsability "explaining" what wire gauges to use, which breakers to choose and so on. (Although I've seen at least warnings about inductive loads (motors) needing breakers with specific curves)

You don't calculate the neutral current correctly.
Assume you have a balanced load with say 10A on each phase of a three phase system.
The phases are not at the same voltage phase angle, and not even in 180 degree anti-phase like the North American split phase system, but the three phases are 120 degrees apart.
It means that a three phase load with 10A on each phase will always cancel out and there is 0A current in the neutral wire.
Now, following that reasoning, if you cut out one phase that was running at 10A to balance out the two other phases, the neutral needs to carry 10A to keep the two remaining phases running at 10A per phase.
You can prove this also by plotting waveform of the Neutral wire, which is now a simple sum of two separate 10A sine wave currents that are at a phase of 120 degrees apart. It's a 10A sine wave too.
Also the notation is not about doubled neutral.
I interpret it as 220 - 240V 1N~ meaning 1 phase and neutral, and the 400V 2N~ meaning two phases and neutral, and with 400V meaning what it usually does, i.e. voltage between two phases, which equals to 230V on each phase, as confirmed by the picture.
And of course the manual does not define recommended cable or breaker size for two reasons.
The manual does not know your local regulations for household mains wiring for this amount of load. Your country defines, i.e. the electrical code by which installations must be made to be legal.
The assumption also is that the installation is performed by an electrician with knowledge of local code and legal permit to work on household mains wiring. Depending on which country you are in, it might be illegal for you to install it unless you are an electrician. In which case you would already know how to install it.
The installation must be legally done according to electrical codes, for continued safety so the house does not burn down or someone gets electrocuted by toucing the hob because of incorrect installation which may develop a fault over some period of time. And insurance company may then require proof who installed the hob and when to see if it was installed by code if it starts a fire.

"You don't calculate the neutral current correctly." that indeed was the source of my confusion.
